# Pycharm: Conda executable path is empty

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, conda

I can't set my conda enviroment in pycharm . Although conda is installed in my system . I am using ubuntu `20.04` . I can see all my virtual environment .

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add set the path of the `conda` executable. To do this, go into your terminal and type in the following command (assuming you have `conda` installed):

```
which conda
```

This should return a path. Use this path as the `conda` executable in PyCharm.