# Cannot add conda environment to Pycharm - Conda executable path is empty even when it's not

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I am pretty proficient in pycharm but it is the first time I stumble into this problem.

1. I created a conda environment
2. Finding the conda executable which for me is in `/home/my_username/.miniconda3/envs/py39/bin/python`
3. Adding it to pycharm results in:
   [image]

I tried to search for this issue and error but the results didnt help.
I am using fedora 36 if it is relevant.

Edit: The output of `which conda` is:

```
/home/my_username/.miniconda3/condabin/conda
```

Then trying to add it as the interpreter as suggested in [Pycharm: Conda executable path is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61975484/pycharm-conda-executable-path-is-empty):
[image]

Comment: What is your pycharm version?

Comment: 2022.2.1 iirc but is there a way to check this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. click the 'add interpreter'-'Add local interpreter';
2. click 'Conda Environment' on the left panel, browse and select 'yourAnacondaDir\Scripts\conda.exe';
3. click 'load Environment';
4. then two options: 'use existing environment' and 'create new environment' show up;
5. click the first option;
6. In the 'Use existing environment' box, select 'your_env'

Answer (score 2):

In the path you should define a path to the `python.exe` in the Conda environment directory.

Here is an example:

[image: Screenshot of Python interpreters in IDE settings]

Comment: see point number 3 in my post, I added the python executable but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

You need to first tell PyCharm where conda executable is. This is not so obvious how, as there is no input field for that when adding existing conda environments. IMO it's a UX flaw in PyCharm.

**I found this input field only available when creating a NEW conda environment from within a PyCharm. Enter a 'Conda executable' there.** In your case: `/home/????/.miniconda3/bin/conda`

Then I also created a new dummy conda environment so the path is stored and PyCharm is happy. Afterwards, you shouldn't get that "Conda executable path is empty" anymore when adding new conda interpreter.

Comment: doesn't work for me on the mac with miniconda. I can confirm the path to the executable is correct and was correct when I opened the settings, but the selector for an environment is always empty with no options

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-installing the OS and now it works, I would not call it a solution but it is what it is - I couldnt waste more time on this as I have work to do.

Answer (score 0):

As the error mentions either you do not have a Conda installed on your system or the path is not recognized by the IDE. Creating a new project, double check if the bar **conda executable:** is **correctly** filled by the directory to the folder Conda is installed on your system.

Normally your IDE fill the conda executable automatically, if this is not the case and manually filling the empty bar did not help, I would recommend to delete and reinstall your conda.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

1. First, check the output of `conda env list` to find the root folder of your conda env.
   Then add your conda environment as if it were an existing virtual environment.
   Provide the full path to the python.exe within the root your conda environment.
2. Close PyCharm.
3. Locate your PyCharm settings folder and find the file `options\jdk.table.xml`. The full path will look something like
   `%AppData%\JetBrains\PyCharm2023.1\options\jdk.table.xml`

In there find the element that corresponds to the newly added environment. Then change the tag

`<setting name="FLAVOR_ID" value="" />` into `<setting name="FLAVOR_ID" value="Conda" />`

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself unable to add an existing or new Conda environment with all the other answers, I resolved the issue by completely quitting PyCharm all together and re-open it.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS - none of the previous posts fixed the issue.
This is the issue:

- Specify the conda path manually in Pycharm
- It lists the environments
- Select one
- Env is NOT saved as your project interpreter
- Conda path is not saved.
- Back to square 0

I tried absolutely everything including completely wiping all JetBrains from all caches, applications settings, everything. It will still not work. The issue is that Pycharm is looking for the conda bin in a specific folder, and it will never work if it's not in the expected folder. Once the conda bin file is in the right location, Pycharm will pick it up automatically.

I fixed it by installing a new copy of conda here:

- wrong_location: `usr/local/anaconda3/` (where conda was installed)
- right_location: `~/miniconda3/` (where you should install conda/miniconda)

(Download conda here: https://docs.conda.io/projects/miniconda/en/latest/)

When installing conda, pick the 'default' right_location, which is the location that Pycharm expects.

I then migrated my environments by just copying them from `wrong_location/envs` to `right_location/envs`.

Start up your Pycharm, and it should now see the conda bin and list your envs, and you can pick from them normally.